# Change Header and Hide text field on selected option change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On a html page i have a drop down and a header. I would like to change the header and hide some field depending on what option is being selected:

Here is the html code:

```
<h1 id ="title_form" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">Contact Form </h1> 

<select class="formInput" id="Contact_contactType" name="Contact_contactType" style="width: 200px;">
    <option value=""></option>

    <option value="1">Congress</option>

    <option value="2">Claimant</option>

    <option value="3">Claimant Representative</option>

    <option value="4">Contract Attorney</option>

    <option value="5">Employer Attorney</option>

    <option value="6">Employer</option>

</select>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
 var ddl = document.getElementById("Contact_claimantType");
 var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;

 if (selectedValue == '0') {

     console.log("Picked Nothing");
     jQuery("#title_form").html = "Contact Form";

 }else if (selectedValue == '1') {

     console.log("Picked Congress");
     jQuery("#title_form").html = "Congress Contact Form";

}else if (selectedValue == '2') {

     console.log("Picked Claimant");
     jQuery("#title_form").html = "Claimant Contact Form";
     edeControl("ConepresentativeType");    
}
```

I have also tried this:

```
jQuery("#Contact_claimantType").change(function(){
   if(jQuery(this).val()=="0")
   {    
        console.log("Picked Nothing");
         jQuery("#title_form").html = "Conrm";

   }else if (jQuery(this).val()=="1"){

        console.log("Picked Congress");
         jQuery("#title_form").html = "Cong Form";


   }else if (jQuery(this).val()=="2"){

       console.log("Picked Claimant");
       jQuery("#title_form").html = "Claimant Contact Form";
       eControl("ContacntativeType");   


   }

});
```

My code currently is not doing anything. It's not even writing anything to the console. Is there anyway i can accomplish what i want either using jQuery or javascript.

Comment: Did you bind your dropdown change event to your code? I see none.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev i am working on the enterprise application the form has three event handler new, save read i attached my script to new also the drop down has 4 event handler blur, change, click, focus i have tried adding the script to change that didn't work either. I am adding new code at the top that i also tried but didn't work.

Comment: Look at my answer below. I hope you will continue to work on Enterprise Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is minimal fix which allows your script to do something:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {//document must be loaded before you can manage DOM
        //var ddl = document.getElementById("Contact_claimantType");//see above
            //var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;//see above
        $('#Contact_contactType').change(function () {//Contact_claimantType not found make sure you use correct IDs
            var selectedValue = this.value;// now we have selected value
            //if (selectedValue == '0') {//you need "0" option which doesn't exist
            if (selectedValue == '') {

                console.log("Picked Nothing");
                //$("#title_form").html = "Contact Form";//jQuery: $ is common nickname for jQuery
                $("#title_form").html("Contact Form");//this way

            } else if (selectedValue == '1') {

                console.log("Picked Congress");
                //$("#title_form").html = "Congress Contact Form";
                $("#title_form").html("Congress Contact Form");

            } else if (selectedValue == '2') {

                console.log("Picked Claimant");
                jQuery("#title_form").html = "Claimant Contact Form";//guess what to do with it
                etk.app.dataForm.hideControl("Contact_claimantRepresentativeType");//nobody knows yet what is "etk"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It isn't charm. It's the first step on the road of thousand lei.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing somehting here, but could you not use the JS to simply change the class ot the HTML elements i.e. the bit you want to hide you'd change to .classname-hidden and add a CSS rule to that of display: none. in terms of the bit you want to change the content on, JS shouldn't really be used to generating content but you could swap it out with a SPAN in the html, then targer that span in CSS and use Content: to add the content. when you want to change said template, again, change the class to a different span class with different content.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple. First you need to setup an event listener on your select list. Next you need to check the value of your select list and finally depending on the value of the function do something.

```
<h1 id ="title_form" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">Contact Form </h1> 

<select class="formInput" id="Contact_contactType" name="Contact_contactType" style="width: 200px;" onchange="myfunction(this)">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">Congress</option>
    <option value="2">Claimant</option>
    <option value="3">Claimant Representative</option>
    <option value="4">Contract Attorney</option>
    <option value="5">Employer Attorney</option>
    <option value="6">Employer</option>
</select>


<script>
    function myfunction(element){
       var selectedValue = element.value;
       if (selectedValue == '0') {
          console.log("Picked Nothing");
          jQuery("#title_form").html = "Contact Form";
       }else if (selectedValue == '1') {
          console.log("Picked Congress");
          jQuery("#title_form").html = "Congress Contact Form";
       }else if (selectedValue == '2') {
          console.log("Picked Claimant");
          jQuery("#title_form").html = "Claimant Contact Form";
          etk.app.dataForm.hideControl("Contact_claimantRepresentativeType");    
       }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this code can help

```
<h1 id ="title_form" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">Contact Form </h1> 

<select onchange="getValue(this);">
    <option value=""></option>

    <option value="1">Congress</option>

    <option value="2">Claimant</option>

    <option value="3">Claimant Representative</option>

    <option value="4">Contract Attorney</option>

    <option value="5">Employer Attorney</option>

    <option value="6">Employer</option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function getValue(item) {
          if (item.value === "1")
            document.getElementById("title_form").innerHTML = "New text!";
    }
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DlanorJQ/e6d2cx8e/

Comment: Hi I added the JsFiddle that I used for make the example